# How to fit this table into Latex

Tags: tables

The margin on the left is quite huge. I was wondering what was the optimal way of fitting this into one latex page.

Anyway here is my code:

```
 \begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Table 1: Naive OLS regressions of consumption on hourly wholesale price}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
 \hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Consumption}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{LogConsumption}&   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Log Consumption}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Consumption}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Consumption}\\
\hline
Hourly price    &    0.237\sym{***}&  0.00215\sym{***}&                    &                  &    0.500\sym{***}\\
            & (0.0333)         &(0.0000844)         &                  &                  & (0.0828)         \\
[1em]
Log hour Price  &                  &                  &    0.191\sym{***}&                  &                  \\
            &                  &                  &(0.00727)         &                  &                  \\
[1em]
Hourly price sq.&                  &                  &                  & 0.000612\sym{***}& -0.00103\sym{***}\\
            &                  &                  &                  &(0.000120)         &(0.000298)         \\
[1em]
Constant        &    213.9\sym{***}&    4.372\sym{***}&    3.727\sym{***}&    229.3\sym{***}&    200.4\sym{***}\\
            &  (3.318)         &(0.00842)         & (0.0322)         &  (1.831)         &  (5.123)         \\
\hline
Observations    &   165600         &   162290         &   161806         &   165600         &   165600         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)&    0.000         &    0.004         &    0.004         &    0.000         &    0.000         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize  }\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Without a full example, it's entirely unclear how this looks.